# DropDownButton não mostra o item selecionado após o setState Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async, dropdown, async-await

Tenho um código onde faz a busca no banco de dados e retorna uma `Future<List>` e estou querendo passar essa lista para o `items` do `DropDownButton` então mapeei essa lista dessa forma:

```
DropdownButton(
  items: snapshot.data
      ?.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(e.toString()),
            value: e,
          ))
      .toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _.selectedNum = value as int;
    });
  })
```

Para o código acima funcionar, usei o `FutureBuilder`, passando como `future` a minha função que retorna a `Future<List>, builder(context,snapshot)`

Logo após, o `setState` no `selectedNum` para receber o novo valor, porém quando seleciono outro valor no `dropDownButton`, seu `value`, não altera conforme mandei no `setState`, mantendo o valor padrão que foi definido como `_.selectedNum = snapshot.data?[0];`

**Observação:**
O `_.selectedNum` está vindo da minha classe `Controller` que tem herança do `GetxController`, estou usando a lib `get` nesse projeto

Código Completo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'dart:async';

Future<List> getNumCasas() async {
  final casas = await getCasas();
  List numCasas = [];
  casas?.forEach((element) {
    numCasas.add(element.numero);
  });
  return numCasas;
}

class Controller extends GetxController {
  int selectedNum = 0;
  void atribuiValor(int value) {
    selectedNum = value;
    update();
  }
}

class AlugarCasa extends StatefulWidget {
  const AlugarCasa({super.key});

  @override
  State<AlugarCasa> createState() => _AlugarCasaState();
}

class _AlugarCasaState extends State<AlugarCasa> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GetBuilder<Controller>(
          init: Controller(),
          builder: (_) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () => Get.back(),
                ),
                title: Text('Alugar Casas'),
              ),
              body: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getNumCasas(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Carregando...',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      _.selectedNum = snapshot.data?[0];
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Insira as informações do inquilino',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('Cpf')),
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('Nome')),
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(label: Text('Celular')),
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(label: Text('Indicação')),
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(label: Text('Observação')),
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text('Número: ${_.selectedNum}'),
                                DropdownButton(
                                    items: snapshot.data
                                        ?.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                              child: Text(e.toString()),
                                              value: e,
                                            ))
                                        .toList(),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _.selectedNum = value as int;
                                      });
                                    })
                              ],
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        EdgeInsets.all(20))),
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.person_add),
                                    Text(
                                      '  Alugar',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar e entender como resolver esse problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: Fala João. A resposta que foi fornecida resolveu seu problema? Se sim, acha que pode aceitá-la? Você pode fazer isso clicando no símbolo de ✔️ ao lado da resposta. Fazer isso contribui com a categorização e eventuais buscas no site. Um abraço.

Answer (score -1):

Parece que existe uma falha na compreensão de dois pontos relacionados entre si. Vamos um de cada vez:

- Primeiro: O future utilizado pelo `FutureBuilder` deve ser armazenado fora dele.

Segundo a [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) da classe `FutureBuilder`:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, [...].
> It must not be created during the State.build [...]. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Traduzindo livremente, isso significa que você não deve *criar* a conexão dentro do `FutureBuilder`. Você fez isso na linha `future: getNumCasas(),`. Quando você faz isso, sempre que essa parte da tela for re-desenhada, a função será chamada de novo e a conexão será reiniciada.

Existem muitos jeitos de resolver esse problema, mas o mais simples é:

1. Iniciar essa conexão no `initState`.
2. Armazenar seu resultado em uma variável da classe de estado.
3. No `futureBuilder`, use a variável que você armazenou.

No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    conexao = getNumCasas(); // Passo 1: Chame a função dentro do initState e armazene em uma variável.
  }

late Future<List> conexao; // Passo 2: A variável criada.

[...]

body: FutureBuilder(
    future: conexao, // Passo 3: Usar no FutureBuilder o future armazenado.
```

- Segundo: O método `build` é chamado sempre que a tela precisar ser redesenhada, e por alguns [outros motivos](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html). Isso significa que variáveis declaradas dentro dele serão re-declaradas sempre que o método for chamado novamente.

Note que você define um valor a sua variável com a linha: `_.selectedNum = snapshot.data?[0];`. Isso ocorre dentro do método `build()`. Sempre que a tela for atualizada, (i.e. quando algum dropdown for selecionado), o código dessa linha será executado novamente e a variável terá seu valor padrão redefinido.

Existem algumas maneiras diferentes para corrigir isso. O importante é você não redefinir essa variável sempre que for desenhar a tela. Vou sugerir uma forma que acredito **não ser a mais elegante** mas é a que mais deixa claro o problema:

Primeiramente, em sua classe controller, adicione um `bool` para saber se já foi atribuído o valor inicial ou não. Esse booleano deve receber valor inicial `false`:

```dart
class Controller extends GetxController {
  int selectedNum = 0;
  bool jaRecebeuValorInicial = false;
[...]
```

Ao passar na linha que você atribui o valor inicial, verifique esse booleano e só atribua caso ela não tenha recebido nenhum valor ainda:

Isto é, mude isto:

```dart
_.selectedNum = snapshot.data?[0];
```

para isto:

```dart
if (!_.jaRecebeuValorInicial){
  _.selectedNum = snapshot.data?[0];
}
```

Com essas alterações o seu código deve trazer o resultado desejado.